# How to delete review of Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, review

As the title says? Clicked on submit before I finished reading that it posts your username and photo.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 11):

You can now just scroll down to the bottom of the extension's page in the Chrome web store, and you'll see an 'Edit' and 'Delete' option for your review.

If that doesn't show, click 'Write a review' again and it should appear. You might need to refresh the page before you have the option to write a review after submitting the first.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Click on review again and then you can delete it.

Comment: I had to scroll down to find the Edit and Delete options. Clicking on the review doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Simply clicking and even refreshing the page wasn't enough for me. I had to reopen it altogether, go back to the first tab, then back to the review tab, and click review.

After all that, it finally showed itself at the very bottom, just below where the rating stars are. This time though, the stars were filled in with the rating I inputted with a "Delete" & "Edit" button below that.

Make sure it shows the correct gmail account in the top right corner. On my work computer, it shows my work gmail so I had to switch it to my personal gmail account. Then after doing that, it still reverted back to my work email as soon as the page was reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you had removed or disabled the extension from chrome, it doest allow you to edit or delete the review. Adding the extension again seems to do the trick.
If extension is already active, try removing and add it again.
The Review Edit option is at the bottom of the review tab.